# Creative Exchange does not import page <body> style in SXA

Tags: sxa

With Creative Exchange styles can be edited in Components or in Page `<body>` tag.

Components works fine out of the box. New styles are added to Sitecore and assigned to components after import as expected.

Page body is not so easy. I added style to the page, but nothing was changed in Sitecore after importing package with that style. My changes are just ignored.

What should I do to import custom style added to `<body>` tag in SXA?

I am using SXA v1.1

Answer (score 2):

Styles from `<body>` tag added to Sitecore `Body Css Style` page field after import. That field is defined by its ID in SXA code:

```cs
public static readonly ID BodyCssClass = new ID("{D4952280-2D7D-4BF4-A99A-EA36DAD0F0A7}");
```

`Body Css Style` field belongs to `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Theming/_Styleable` template.

The problem is, SXA pages are not inherited from that template after site is scaffolded.

To fix that, you need to open `Page` template for your tenant - `/sitecore/templates/Project/My Tenant/Page` and add `_Styleable` to `Base templates`.

After that is done, reimport Creative Exchange package and you style will appear in `Body Css Style` field.